# How to select tab in uiTabBarController using a custom center button

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard

I have a storyboard enabled App with a TabBarController where I have added viewcontrollers through the interface builder.

Then I followed the [iDevReceipes](http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/) post to add a custom button in the center, which hide my third or center tab bar item with a custom button.

I'm not able to make the TabBarController select the middle tab when a user clicks the button. I wired the button with a selector and within the method I added a code which was supposedly  a solution which worked for many on Stack Overflow i.e `self.tabBarController.SelectedIndex = 2;` this was called in viewWillAppear

This is somehow not working and selecting the correct tab. I had a NSLog inside the method of the button and I found out the button works but the tab is not getting selected.

The tabbarcontroller has a class with nothing inside this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but you need to use a setter method and not set the property directly; this is one instance where it does make a difference. Also, I may be misunderstanding you, but you need to call this code in the selector for the button, not in the `viewWillAppear` method. Here's the code you'll use to select the middle index.

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];
```